# Perché "aspetta un taxi" e non "aspetta per un taxi"?

Tags: verbs, grammar, prepositions

Ciao a tutti, sto studiando l'italiano da 3 mesi, ma la grammatica non è ancora facile per me.

Nella frase *aspetta un taxi* (wait for a taxi) perché non si mette *per* prima di "un taxi" (I am waiting **for** a taxi and not a taxi)?

Grazie per le risposte :)

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Mi sono permesso di correggere alcuni errori nella tua domanda.

Comment: It's kind of funny question. By the same token, as an Italian, I could ask “Why ‘waiting for a taxi’ and not ‘wait a taxi’”? Good dictionaries of all languages give, for every word, how it is used, that is, which preposition, cases, tenses etc. are to be used with it, since it varies enormously from language to language, even for apparently similar words. Never give anything for granted!

Answer (score 4):

L'inglese e l'italiano sono lingue diverse. In italiano si dice

- aspetto un taxi
- ascolto la radio

In inglese sarebbero

- I'm waiting *for* a taxi
- I'm listening *to* the radio

Verbi che sono transitivi in italiano corrispondono a verbi intransitivi in inglese. O il contrario! L'inglese

- I answered Ryan's question

diventa

- Ho risposto alla domanda di Ryan

Il verbo “to answer” è transitivo in inglese, ma “rispondere” è intransitivo in italiano.

Se dicessi “ascolto alla radio” mancherebbe qualcosa: che cosa sto ascoltando? Quindi “ascolto la radio” (quello che danno) oppure “ascolto alla radio un'opera” (“opera” è il complemento oggetto, ciò che sto ascoltando).

A volte *aspettare* può essere usato come apparente intransitivo, come giustamente osserva carlo_borreo nei commenti:

- *aspetto per un minuto*
- *aspetto da molto tempo*

ma in questi casi c'è una subordinata relativa, implicita come nelle frasi precedenti o esplicita

- *aspetto per un minuto che tu arrivi*
- *aspetto da molto tempo che piova*

Comment: Giusto, pero' possiamo dire "aspetto per un minuto", quando si aspetta un tempo specificato

Comment: @carlo.borreo Vero, in qualche caso un verbo transitivo può essere usato come intransitivo. Anche *aspetto da molto tempo*. Ma non sono del tutto sicuro dell'intransitività qui, perché ci vedo una relativa implicita.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, grammar constructs are always somewhat arbitrary. Even considering English alone, why do you "listen *to* a tune", but "watch a movie", or "hear a tune" without the *to*? The meaning is comparable, but one verb needs a *to* and one doesn't.

In particular, these arbitrary constructs do not always translate 1:1 across languages. In German, for instance, you *thank to someone*. In Italian, as you have discovered, we *wait someone*, with no preposition.

These constructions are one of the difficulties in learning a new language, and it takes study and habit to get used to them.